# Disabling checkboxes that are not checked with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How do I disable ALL checkboxes on a page that are not checked? Do I need to first scan through all the checkboxes or is there a simpler way? I'm still a jQuery newbie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Obviously a user won't be able to ever select them again, as you've disabled them...

```
$(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
```

See the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/), [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector, as well as the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) method.

If you're not using jQuery 1.6.x, then you won't have the `prop()` method; so use the `attr()` method instead:

```
$(':checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
```

You can see this working in a jsfiddle that was posted in the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/LRL2k/1/

Comment: @Loktar: Thanks! Feel free to improve answers without asking!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) to get all checkboxes, and then use `:not(:checked)` to filter that to the ones that aren't checked  ([`:not` docs](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), [`:checked` docs](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)).

```
$(':checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 3):

This will find all the checkboxes which are not `checked`.

```
$(':checkbox:not(:checked)');
```

Now you can either use `prop` or `attr` method to set the `disabled` property on the matched checkboxes.

```
$(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
```